# find page size and number of pages of a process in linux

Tags: linux, unix, process

Given a PID of the process running in Linux (latest kernel), how do I find out:

1. The number of pages it is using
2. The size of each page it is using (4K, 2MB or 1GB)

This is for x86-64 architecture.

Answer (score 3):

Pagesize is system wide and can be found with the `getconf` command

```
getconf PAGESIZE
```

The [mem_usage.py](http://wingolog.org/archives/2007/11/27/reducing-the-footprint-of-python-applications) tool can provide some more detailed information on a processes memory usage.

Comment: ok, I got it , its is called MMUPageSize and it appears in /proc/pid/statm

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how verbose the information you want should be, you want one of the following:

- `/proc/pid/statm`: Provides information about memory usage, measured in pages.
- `/proc/pid/status`: Provides much of the information from `/proc/pid/statm`, but is easier to read.

Check out the man-page for the proc-files for thorough documentation of what the different columns mean.

- http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc

Comment: well, 'statm' doesn't provide info per page size. What if my process uses 10 pages of 4K size, 20 pages of 2MB size and 1 page of 1GB size? neither 'status' provides info about the amount of each page size.

Comment: @Nulik do you know if you have huge pages enabled ?

Comment: @Iain yes, /proc/filesystems says  "nodev hugetlbfs"

Comment: btw, man 5 proc don't show the latest changes for 2.6.34

Answer (score 2):

> The number of pages it is using

```
awk '{ print $24 }' /proc/[pid]/stat
```

or:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' /proc/[pid]/statm
```

According to the [man proc](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html), it is the number of pages the process has in real memory. Also take a look at the [procstat.c](http://brokestream.com/procstat.html) to display proc stat in human readable format.